# java.lang.SecurityException: com.myapp.android does not match with registered signature. FE:05:..01

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm attempting to read health data from Samsung Health on a Samsung device and when I do so I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: com.myapp.android does not match with registered signature. FE:05...:01
```

I have absolutely no clue what this means. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to enable developer mode and become a partner (which sadly is not permitted as this time).

https://developer.samsung.com/health/android/data/guide/dev-mode.html#How-to-Activate-the-Developer-Mode